# Thymeleaf - get a variable from loop to action url

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a problem with this code:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/categories/category}">
    <select name="category">
        <option th:each="category : ${categoriesList}" th:text="${category.name}" th:value="${category.id}"/>
    </select>
    <select name="language">
        <option value="ENGLISH">Angielski</option>
        <option value="GERMAN">Niemiecki</option>
        <option value="FRENCH">Francuski</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I don't know how to insert category ID into url in the first line of code instead of 'category'. So it should looks like that:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/categories/CATEGORY_ID}">
```

Is there any option to link it dynamically according to selected option from select?

Comment: No way to do this in thymeleaf.  You'll have to use javascript.

Comment: Can you not use an input type="hidden" with CATEGORY_ID?

Comment: If an answer helped you, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `th:each` up one level to the `select` element.

Comment: This would repeat the select tag and that is not what he wants.

Answer (score 0):

In Thymeleaf you can't use a variable in the same tag you defined it.
Instead you can use the invisible th:block tag:

```
<select name="category">
  <th:block th:each="category : ${categoriesList}">
    <option th:text="${category.name}" th:value="${category.id}"/>
  </th:block>
</select>
```